# How to write String from variable to text file

Tags: java, filewriter, bufferedwriter

My goal here is to read lines from a text file, check if they are palindromes, and then write those to a completely different file.

Now the problem, as far as I can see, lies in the if statement block where I check for palindromes successfully but can't seem to write them to another file because they are stored in a variable.

When I use the BufferedWriter write method and set the parameters as an actual string with quotes, everything works.

How can I solve this?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class Zadatak14 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BufferedReader br;

        try {

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Luka\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\CS101-DZ14-14\\src\\zadatak14\\ulaz.txt"));

            String line;
            

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                String palindrome = new StringBuilder(line).reverse().toString();

                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Luka\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\CS101-DZ14-14\\izlaz.txt"));
                
                
                
                
                if (line.contains(palindrome)) {

                    System.out.println(line);

                    bw.write(line);

                }

                bw.close();

            }

            br.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Greska");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Greska");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What output or errors are you getting? See [mcve].

Comment: I'm not getting anything, no errors or outputs. It's that the file I'm supposed to write in is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter`

You're making a new writer **for every line in your input**, which surely you don't want. Move the creation of the writer up top, right after opening the reader.

> `br.close();`

not how you do that. This is how you do that:

```
try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("...."))) {
   // code here
}
// no matter how you get out of this code, the file is closed.
```

The reason you do it with the above is because that `bw.close()` won't get called if exceptions occur, if you `return` out of the block. With the try construct, that stream is closed when code exits from the block no matter how it does that.

```
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Greska");
```

Not how you do that - exceptions contain a lot of useful info (at least 4 things, more for some specific kinds of exceptions: type, message, stack trace, cause), and you're tossing it all in the garbage. It's a bad idea to toss information about problems in the bin. Don't. The right move is to add `throws Exception` to your `public static void main(String[] args)` method, and then you don't need a catch at all. If you must, the correct body for a catch block if you don't have a good way to handle the problem, is `throw new RuntimeException("Uncaught", e);`. This preserves all information and doesn't cause errors about having to catch exceptions.